# How to experiment with private APIs on iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios, iphone-privateapi

I have been exploring private APIs within iOS for the express purpose of experimentation. Does anyone have a sample of instantiating a class like MKTransitAnnotationView?

I've downloaded Erica Sadun's [HeaderDumpKit](http://ericasadun.com/HeaderDumpKit/) and the [class-dump](http://www.codethecode.com/projects/class-dump/) binary. After making a few corrections to her perl script I dumped out a Headers directory and moved that into the project folder.

In the Other Linker Flags section of Build Settings I added:

```
-force_flat_namespace
-undefined suppress
```

When trying to call MKTransitAnnotationView I get dyld: Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_MKTransitAnnotationView. So what have I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your dumped header as a normal header file, then from your project navigator:

- click on your project
- click on your target
- click on the Build Phases tab, then expand the Link Binary With Libraries section
- drag/drop the binary from PrivateFramework folder that you want to use.

Then you should be all set.

Normally you shouldn't have to change your flags.